# <br/> not working on text from a mysql query

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, json

I'm working on a project where an A.I is pushing text on a MySQL database. Then, we want to show the ongoing writing happening on a webpage. We're still working on it.

We're getting the data and regulary checking the DB for new entry. The problem is, we would like to separate each text with a space and tried to use `<br/>` or `<p>` but it doesn't work, it seems to be "just" text and shown like this.

Our code :

```
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #myTable{ 
           width:"90%";
           min-width: 250px;
           word-wrap:break-word;
           overflow:visible; 
           position:absolute;
           border:solid 0px;
           top:250px;
           left:720px;
           right:720px;
           bottom:50px;
           font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
           text-align:justify
        } 
   </style> 

</head>
<body>
    <div id="myTable"> <div>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var skip = 0;
        function get_data(index) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'getData.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data: ({"skip":skip}),
                success : function(data) { 
                    if(data && data.trim()!='') {
                        skip = skip+1;
                        showText("#myTable", data, 0, 5); 
                    }
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function () { get_data(skip); }, 30000);
                    }
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request error : "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }

        function showText(target, message, index, interval) {   
            if (index < message.length) {
                $(target).append(message[index++]);
                setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
            }
            else {
                get_data(skip);
            }
        }

        //var period = 10000; //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
        get_data(skip);
        //setInterval(page_refresh, period); 
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What is it doing that's undesirable?

Comment: your code has neither <p> nor <br/> in it, where are you inserting it?

Comment: <p> or/and <br/> tags are from the datas shown through MySQL requests, not in this code. This code is for setting up the way the text will be shown on screen.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL if you contact `CHAR(13)` to any string it will give you a line break.

```
DECLARE @textBreaking NVARCHAR(50)
SET @textBreaking = 'FIRST LINE.' + CHAR(13) + 'FIRST LINE.'
SELECT @textBreaking
```

On select this block will return the following:

> FIRST LINE.
>   SECOND LINE.

---

Having the text from SQL and displaying it on web page should achieve what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Appending message inside an element tag `<div>`, `<p>` or other,
`$(target).append('<p>' +message[index++]+ '</p>');`

and then setting a Style for that tag with margin or padding to separate each message.

```
p {
  margin-bottom:15px;
  margin-top:15px;
  //or
  padding-bottom:15px;
  padding-top:15px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Analyzing your `http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/getData.php` shows that don't have any `<br />` tags, but `\n` instead in your output.

In your JS-code you need to replace `\n` with `<br />`.#

I assume that `message[index++]` holds your text, so:

```
$(target).append(message[index++].replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: Don't do that. Instead, use CSS `white-space: pre-wrap` to make the browser pay attention to spaces and newlines.

Comment: Definitely agree not to use <br /> but <p> tags would be equally acceptable.  you could prepend <p> Append </p> and replace "\n" with "</p><p>"

Comment: I can't just add a <br> in the text pushed by the AI and shown through getData.php ?

Comment: Please show us the code where you have tried to do that and we'll be able to help.  Although I would suggest that you store the data as data, and add markup for presentation only when it is presented, that way the data can be used for multiple purposes.

Comment: @MathieuArbezHermoso, you can do that too.
@NiettheDarkAbsol why not to use `<br />` since its valid and xml-conform?

Comment: @Just_Do_It it was in the first version of the question.

Comment: white-space: pre-wrap will force the browser to pay attention to the <p> tag right ?

Comment: <br/> seems to not work where white-space: pre-wrap works like a charm :)